# Cell divider in table not long enough

Tags: tables, longtable, pdfpages, includegraphics

When using a longtable environment where I include a pdf as the content of one of the columns, the adjacent separator lines are not sufficiently long:

[image]

My code is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable} {| >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1in} | >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1in} | >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1in} |}
  \hline \\
  bla & bli & \includegraphics{blablu.pdf} \\
  \hline \\
  blo & blok & \includegraphics{blablu.pdf} \\
  \hline 
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: never use `\\ ` after `\hline` (longtable is the same as standard tabular here)

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick! :)

Comment: Consider accepting the provided answer to "close" the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never use `\\`  after `\hline` (longtable is the same as standard tabular here).